# Regex using grep in bash gives unwanted output at the end

Tags: regex, bash, filereader

I am iterating through a text file line by line in bash and printing out the word segments that match the relevant regex pattern. This process is done by accepting the text file as an argument. My code works fine but at the end, in the last line, an unwanted output gets printed. I am new to bash and I have no idea why this is happening. Shown below is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
pat='[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.png'
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n $line ]];do
   echo $line | grep -o -P $pat
done < "$1"
```

shown below is the output(the unwanted line is the highlighted one):

[image]

I want to get rid of this last line of unwanted output.

Comment: You may directly use `grep`: `grep -oE $pat "$1"`. Or directly `grep -oE $pat file`

Comment: when you say "directly" does that mean that the while loop is not needed?

Comment: If you are extracting every single match from a file a loop is redundant. Note you are using `P` option but the regex is POSIX BRE compliant, you may omit `P`. Use `grep -o '[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.png' file` or - to save matches in a file - `grep -o '[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.png' file > newfile`

Comment: Do you just want  the matched words from each line?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just need to list the files. So basically this would do? 
echo |  grep -o  $pat $1

Comment: If `$1` is a file path, use `grep -o $pat "$1"`

Comment: Is there a particular reason for putting $1 inside inverted commas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're running the script with `sh` instead of `bash`. `[[` is a `bash` extension, it's not available in `sh`. So change

```
sh test2.sh summary.md
```

to

```
bash test2.sh summary.md
```

Or, since the script starts with `#!/bin/bash`, just use:

```
./test.sh summary.md
```

You should also quote all the variables in the script. See [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)